# Generate presigned s3 URL of latest object in the bucket using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a s3 bucket with multiple folders. How can I generate s3 presigned URL for a latest object using python boto3 in aws for each folder asked by a user?

Comment: **Side-note:** Typically, applications create pre-signed URLs at the time that they are requested. This is because they are **time-limited**, so creating the pre-signed URLs before they are needed will either result in the URL expiring, or will require a long-lived URL that is not good for security.

Comment: What do you mean by "for each folder asked by a user"?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a small bucket then recursively list the bucket, with prefix as needed. Sort the results by timestamp, and create the pre-signed URL for the latest.

If it's a very large bucket, this will be very inefficient and you should consider other ways to store the key of the latest file. For example: trigger a Lambda function whenever an object is uploaded and write that object's key into a LATEST item in DynamoDB (or other persistent store).

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config
import requests
bucket = 'bucket-name'
folder = '/' #you can add folder path here don't forget '/' at last

s3 = boto3.client('s3',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

objs = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=folder)['Contents']     
latest = max(objs, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
print(latest)

print (" Generating pre-signed url...")
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': bucket,
        'Key': latest['Key']
    }
)
print(url)
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.url)
```

here it will give the latest last modified file from the whole bucket however you can update login and update prefix value as per need.

if you are using Kubernetes POD, VM, or anything you can pass environment variables or use the python dict to store the latest key if required.